# how to fix "Cannot subscript a value of type 'ClosedRange<Int>' with an index of type 'Int' in swift"

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, countdowntimer, numberpicker

I wanna prepare a basic number picker timer for my homework but I cannot fix this problem.

```
var timer = Timer()
    var counter = 0

    //let number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"]

    let number = 1 ... 60

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return number[row]
    }




    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return number.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        label.text = number[row]

    }
```

But it gives this error.

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'ClosedRange' with an index of type 'Int'

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of strings `[String]` but you declare an integer range `ClosedRange<Int>`

Create an array from the range and map the items to `String`

```
let number = Array(1...60).map(String.init)
```

It's recommended to declare arrays in plural form `let numbers`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array, so you need to have square brackets around the range.

```
let numbers = [1...60]
```

Comment: not working. Cannot convert return expression of type 'ClosedRange<Int>' to return type 'String?'

Comment: The result type of `[1...60]` is  `Array<ClosedRange<Int>>` rather than `Array<Int>`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
let numbers = Array(1...60)
```

**How does this work?**

You can explore this yourself.  A trick is to add the explicit `init` call:

```
Array.init(1...60)
```

and then <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `init`.  When you do that, you get:

> **Summary**
>
> Creates an array containing the elements of a sequence. Declaration
>
> ```
> init<S>(_ s: S) where Element == S.Element, S : Sequence
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> You can use this initializer to create an array from any other type
>   that conforms to the Sequence protocol. For example, you might want to
>   create an array with the integers from 1 through 7. Use this
>   initializer around a range instead of typing all those numbers in an
>   array literal.
>
> ```
> let numbers = Array(1...7)
> print(numbers)
> // Prints "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]"
> ```